# Netbeans does not show my code

Tags: netbeans, restore

I have worked in project for long time but after electricity has cut off and my PC shutdown.

The code in one of my frames not shown correctly, it's showing like this :

[image: no code!]

I have GUI and its shape is fine. When I run the frame from main interface it works, but as I said the code is corrupted. I don't know why.  If any one has any solution for this problem it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you open the file in Notepad without any issues?

Comment: And you don't have a code repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Netbeans IDE,

Open **Projects** window (Ctrl+1) ,select **file-> right click** on list select **Local History**-> Select Local History. It will show all your last edits. you can restore the last updates from there.

In Latest netbeans releases you can directly access this from toolbar, check the below screenshot.I took this from Netbeans 7.3

[image]